# Extending Django Admin Templates - altering change list

Tags: django, django-admin

A (not so) quick question about extending django admin templates.

I'm trying to change the result list (change list in django lingo) of a specific model by adding an intermediary row between the result rows (row1 and row2 classes) that contains some objects related to that object.

I searched the code but haven't found a way to do this. Any pointers are very much appreciated. Code will also help too.

PS: I know I should be designing my own interface, but this is an internal project and I don't have that much time to spare. Also, the django interface is really nice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There exists some functions for admin.py that helps you to override regular methods... [Check it out in here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods)... They may help you...

Answer (score 45):

To expand on Yuji's answer, here are some specifics on overriding `change_list_results.html` ...

---

Override `changelist_view` as described above in step 1, and also described [here at djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view). ***Or*** auto-override by placing in the appropriate directory as in step 2 above. (Note that the step 2 path shown above is model-specific. App-specific would be `/admin/<MyAppName>/change_list.html` under any directory defined in the TEMPLATE_DIRS tuple.)

***Or*** (perhaps easier) simply specify `ModelAdmin.change_list_template` as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_list_template) with any discoverable template filename. (Although, if you retain the name `change_list.html`, be sure not to deposit directly into the `/admin` folder, else the `extends` tag will cause a recursion.)

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'change_list.html' # definitely not 'admin/change_list.html'
    # ...
```

---

In your `change_list.html` template, have at a minimum

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static admin_list %}
{% load myapptags %}

{% block result_list %}
  {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
  {% result_list cl %}
  {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

Create a `/<MyAppName>/templatetags` package (a directory containing `__init__.py`) with a file corresponding to the load tag above

```
# MyAppName/templatetags/myapptags.py

from django import template
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list import result_list

register = template.Library()
register.inclusion_tag('my_change_list_results.html')(result_list)
```

---

Copy and edit Django's `change_list_results.html` (as e.g. `my_change_list_results.html` above) to use your added functionality.

Note that these steps do not include extra context for the template, but can easily be expanded as such. (My reason for doing this was to add classes for CSS and a leading `<tbody>` that was not sorted with the results list.)

---

**ADDITIONAL**:

To include extra context, change your templatetags module as follows:

```
# MyAppName/templatetags/myapptags.py

from django import template
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list import result_list as admin_list_result_list

def result_list(cl):
    mycl = {'myextracontext': 'something extra'}
    mycl.update(foo_extra())
    mycl.update(admin_list_result_list(cl))
    return mycl

register = template.Library()
register.inclusion_tag('my_change_list_results.html')(result_list)
```

Then, the value of `myextracontext` or whatever `foo_extra` returns can be included in your results template (as e.g. `{{ myextracontext }}`)

Comment: I couldn't understand the structure of this answer!

Comment: @Pranab I bet the author couldn't understand what exactly you didn't understand either... Perhaps being a bit more explicit next time could help :)

Answer (score 40):

**Step 1: Overriding changelist view**:
You'll have to override a template as opposed to specifying one like you can with `add_view / change_view`.

First things first, override 
    `def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):` in your `ModelAdmin`. Remember to call `super(foo, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)` and to return that.

**Step 2: Overriding templates**:
Next, override the app-specific changelist template at `templates/admin/my_app/my_model/change_list.html` (or not.. you can use a global changelist override too if you'd like).

**Step 3: Copy result list functionality**
I think you can either copy `result_list` functionality (define a new template tag) or fake it by copying and pasting the result_list function and template include into your view.

```
# django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list
def result_list(cl):
    """
    Displays the headers and data list together
    """
    return {'cl': cl,
            'result_hidden_fields': list(result_hidden_fields(cl)),
            'result_headers': list(result_headers(cl)),
            'results': list(results(cl))}
result_list = register.inclusion_tag("admin/change_list_results.html")(result_list)
```

You can see the admin uses this `admin/change_list_results.html` template to render individual columns so you'll need to use one of the methods to replace this template tag.

Since it's looking for a global template, I wouldn't override it.

Either define a new tag w/ new template specifically for your view, or send `result_list(cl)` to your template directly and adopt the `admin/change_list_results.html` for use directly in your `change_list.html` template.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I had to debug the attributes of cl in result_list(cl) a bit. Other than that - huge thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a complete override of the `admin_list` template tag, here is my post in another thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55597294/11335685

I know it is not directly related to the `change_list` template, but the logic for it lays on the functions inside the `admin_list` template tag.

A disadvantage of that approach is i didn't find a way of overriding only specific function and get use of the other ones.

Still that was the only approach that was allowing me to not mess with the html templates and only alter the behavior of `result_list` function.

Hope that helps anyone.