# Django Admin : Grouped data in the list

Tags: python, django, admin

Can I show a grouped result in Django Admin? By default, they are showing all rows, I want to group these rows based on some fields, and display it.

Something like "GROUP BY username" or stuff. I've tried to search but no luck :(

Comment: Can you clarify, "Group By" as in order or as in filter? =)

Comment: You have to subclass admin classes and write templates. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794528/extending-django-admin-templates-altering-change-list

Comment: It's a really old question, but did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `list_filter='my_field'` in the admin.py file ?

Comment: [list_filters](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) add filters and does not change ordering

Comment: I don't think he wants to order, he speaks about grouping / filtering the results. I hope I get it right :-)

Comment: Hmm, after rereading the initial question. you might be right. =)

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can.

this applies to the detail view of the records.
Here is an example listed below.

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SpecieForm
    list_display = ('species', 'latin_name', 'family', 'status')
    search_fields = ['species', 'latin_name']
    prepopulated_fields = { 'slug': ['species'] }
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']}),
        ('Image', {'fields': ['original_image']}),
        ('Other Group', {'fields': ['other_field1', 'other_field2', 'other_field3', 'other_field4']}),
    ]

admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would be a good answer if it was about grouping form fields, but it is abot grouping list rows.