# Django Admin Grouped data in the list and sum

Tags: python, django

[image]

Can I show a grouped result in Django Admin? By default, they are showing all rows, I want to group these rows based on some fields, and display it.

Something like "GROUP BY Artista" or stuff. I've tried to search but no luck :(

Comment: Would this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698957/django-admin-grouped-data-in-the-list

Comment: I could have ordered now need to group. must turn 5 lines in 1 line

Comment: sounds like maybe the `django-admin-tools` may help https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-admin-tools