# override django admin change_list_results.html per model

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm trying to override `change_list_results.html` only for a particular model. I tried copying the file as with the other templates in the corresponding tree directory ( `templates/admin/APP/MODEL` ), but this method didn't work. I see in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model) that overriding per app/model is possible, but it is not described the special method to achieve this. I found some related answer about [overriding change_list.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794528/extending-django-admin-templates-altering-change-list/4796365#4796365), but I want to override only change_list_results.html and I can't understand how to accomplish just that. What is the way to do this override?

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same issue and found this old post. I imagine you fixed yours.

Anyways, what I was doing wrong was to use the plural name of the model and I was also using the lowercase name. You have to be sure of the following:

- Save your template in /templates/admin/APP/MODEL as you said
- Check your lower/upper cases in the names of the models
- This sounds silly, but just in case...Don't use the plural name of the model

Good luck!

Comment: Had the same problem, I had a model whose name was made of two words (FooMoo). In the admin interface it is rewritten as 'foo_moo', but to override the template you need to create a directory called 'foomoo'

Answer (score 2):

This may have changed since freethinker6's answer: [change_list_results.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#L312) is currently hardcoded.

Comment: "For each app in INSTALLED_APPS, the app_directories.Loader looks for a templates subdirectory. If the directory exists, Django looks for templates in there."
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader)

Comment: You can override this template with your own file. However, this override will apply to all models within the admin, and the question asks how to override it for a single model.

Comment: The method posted by freethinker6 and Kaël below works, at least for Django 3.2.4 which I am using.