# django admin filter data after selection

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In the admin, would it be possible to filter selection from a live input in a field:

```
class ReadtToday(models.Model):
    author =  models.ForeignKey(Authors)                           # field 1)
    book = models.OneToOneField(Books, related_name='bookofday')   # field 2)
```

Now in the admin for 1) and 2) got a list of all of them, how I should proceed to get this behavior:

> select author from field 1) 
>   autoupdate field 2) list with only data
>   from current selected author selected by field 1).

```
class BooksList(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(BooksList, self).get_queryset(request)           
        return qs.filter(HowCanIGetAuthor=from_input_of_field_1)
```

Is possbile to apply field 1) selection to filter fields 2) using `raw_id_fields`?

Comment: It is possible using ajax request to custom view ...
read this http://bit.ly/1EIa7P8 and this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19910749/3033586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way is to implement author selection as a form with submit type GET and check the request.GET inside ModelAdmin class

```
<form method="GET">
   <select name="author">
        <option>An author</option>
   </select>
</form>

def get_queryset(self, request):
    author = request.GET['author']
    qs = super(BooksList, self).get_queryset(request)           
    return qs.filter(author=author)
```

Comment: thanks for the advice! where I can look to understand how to add those form properties to the admin form field?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794528/extending-django-admin-templates-altering-change-list