# Display show_all button on top of django admin page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

`Show_all` button is displayed on the bottom of the page in django admin.

How can I display the **Show_all** button on the top of the page?

Currently `Show_all` is displayed at the bottem of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option or attribute to show this link at top.

The best approach will be to override the `change_list` template of admin, and add a link to show all. There is a stackoverflow [post for this task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794528/extending-django-admin-templates-altering-change-list)

Link need the parameter `all=` like :
 http://localhost:8000/admin/app/model/?all=