# How to access to queryset in change_list block content for Django ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django

I need to access to queryset (including filtering, searching, etc)that is used to generate list in change_list.html

This is in django 2.2.1 and Python 3.6

admin.py

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'city')
    list_display_links = ('name', 'city')
    list_filter = ('city', )
    search_fields = ('name', )

    change_list_template = 'admin/contacts/company/change_list.html'

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

change_list.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}

{% block content %}
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

I would like to achieve somethig like this:

```
{% block content %}
{% for item in list %}
//and there iterate over all items of list 
{% endfor %}
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What about this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794528/extending-django-admin-templates-altering-change-list

Comment: @JPG Still not this. I would like to access to change_list and work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is

```
{% block content %}
{% for item in cl.queryset %}
{{ item }} 
{% endfor %}
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

it is list of queries